# How do I display the value set in signup into seevalue() function? parameter

Tags: c#

How to do I display the value I set in signup() into seevalue() function. 
I want the user to be able to set value and see them in seevalue() function.

namespace MyApp
{
    class members
    {
        public string name_;
        public int age_;
        public double salary_; 
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age_; }
            set { age_ = value; }

```
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name_; }
        set { name_ = value; }
    }
    public double Salary
    {
        get { return salary_; }
        set { salary_ = value; }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            menu();

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "1")
            {
                Signup();
            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
                seeValue(newMn);
            }
            else if ( input == "3")
            {
                Quit();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("sign up: ");
        Console.WriteLine("See members: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Quite: ");

    }
    public static int Signup()
    {
        members newMn = new members();
        Console.Write("Whats your name: ");

        newMn.name_ = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Whats your age: ");
        newMn.age_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Whats yor salary income: ");
        newMn.salary_ = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


        return 1;

    }

    public  static void seeValue( members newMn)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(newMn);
    }
    static void Quit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your `Signup()` method, please?

Comment: I'd be shocked if this compiles.  You make a call to seeValue which is expecting a members parameter, but in the Main() you call seeValue() with no parameters.

Answer (score 0):

this is all my code

namespace MyApp
{
    class members
    {
        public string name_;
        public int age_;
        public double salary_; 
        public int Age
        {
            get { return age_; }
            set { age_ = value; }

```
    }
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return name_; }
        set { name_ = value; }
    }
    public double Salary
    {
        get { return salary_; }
        set { salary_ = value; }

    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();

            menu();

            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input == "1")
            {
                Signup();
            }
            else if (input == "2")
            {
                seeValue(newMn);
            }
            else if ( input == "3")
            {
                Quit();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void menu()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("sign up: ");
        Console.WriteLine("See members: ");
        Console.WriteLine("Quite: ");

    }
    public static int Signup()
    {
        members newMn = new members();
        Console.Write("Whats your name: ");

        newMn.name_ = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.Write("Whats your age: ");
        newMn.age_ = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Whats yor salary income: ");
        newMn.salary_ = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());


        return 1;

    }

    public  static void seeValue( members newMn)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(newMn);
    }
    static void Quit()
    {
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
```

}